# Limite de caracteres

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Preciso limitar caracteres em um texto, e deve ficar com (...).
O titulo fica saindo fora do layout.

```
if($related){
    echo '
    <div class="row">
        <div class="medium-12 columns">
            <div class="ap-ads-related">
                <h2>Anúncios Relacionados</h2>
                <div class="row">
    ';

    foreach ($related as $key => $rel) {
        $related_images = $this->ads_model->images($rel->ad_id);
        $related_image = thumbnail(@$related_images[0]->ads_img_file, "ads", 260, 180, 2);

        echo '
            <div class="small-6 medium-3 end columns">
                <a href="'.base_url('anuncio/'.$rel->ad_slug).'" title="'.$rel->ad_name.'" class="item">
                    <div class="image"><img alt="'.$rel->ad_name.'" src="'.$related_image.'"></div>

                    <h4>'.$rel->ad_name.'</h4>

                    <div class="price">'.(($rel->ad_service) ? 'Serviço' : string_money($rel->ad_price)).'</div>
                </a>
            </div>
        ';
    }
    echo '
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    ';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 6):

O próprio Codeigniter tem uma função para isso, acredito que deve estar utilizando pois tagueou o mesmo na pergunta. Você pode limitar por caracteres ou por palavras, segue código:

```
<?php print character_limiter($rel->ad_name, 25); ?>
```

Irá limitar por 25 caracteres e após isto irá inserir ...

```
<?php print word_limiter($rel->ad_name, 25); ?>
```

Irá limitar por 25 palavras e após irá nserir ...

Caso tenha dúvidas, segue link do Codeigniter com algumas informações:
https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/text_helper.html

Comment: @Willian eu não pesquisei uma solução com CodeIgniter, falha minha, eu fiz uma solução manual usando um helper, porém a solução aqui do parceiro não reinventa a roda. (+1), o que não quer dizer que a minha não é útil, mas essa realmente foi melhor

Comment: Sou meio leigo em codeigneiter, poderia passar o código completo correto? queria ver se funciona

Comment: Basta inserir no lugar de $rel->ad_name isso: print character_limiter($rel->ad_name, 25), faça o teste.

Answer (score 1):

Criei um helper chamado `my_strings.php` na pasta `Application/Helpers`

```
<?php

  function cortaTexto($string, $maxLength){
     if(strlen($string) <= $maxLength)
        return $string;

     return substr($string, 0, $maxLength) . '...';
  }

?>
```

Adicione esse helper no `autoload.php`,

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('html', 'url', 'my_strings');
```

Então na View:

```
cortaTexto($rel->ad_name, 30)
```

Answer (score 1):

Cara, você também pode resolver isso com css.

Esta ai os links que me ajudaram quando eu precisei,

http://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973570/setting-a-max-character-length-in-css

### UPDATE

Defina a largura do container e coloque `text-overflow: ellipsis` e ao chegar no limite do container o texto será automaticamente substituido por `...`

Veja exempli tirado do css-tricks

```
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo bem simples:

```
$string = 'String para ser reduzida'
$reduzido = substr_replace($string, (strlen($string) > 42 ? '...' : ''),42);
```

Espero que ajude.